# Laravel Pluck fails to work on a model

Tags: php, laravel-5

Am trying to pluck id on a certain data but fails

```
$id=PermissionsAssignment::pluck('permission')->
       where('category', $request->filter_category)->all();
```

When i check `var_dump($request->filter_category)` it has eg:1

When i perform

```
 $data= PermissionsAssignment::where('category','=', $request->filter_category)->get();
```

It produces

```
[
   {name:'', permission:1, category:1}
   {name:'two', permission:2, category:1}

         ....etc
]
```

Why is pluck not working as i expect it to return the permission values.

Comment: Pluck will perform the query and therefore only `permission` will be available in the underlying collection. You need to do the `where` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `all()` call and only use `pluck()`

```
$id=PermissionsAssignment::where('category', $request->filter_category)
                         ->pluck('permission');
```